# How can I make an HTML5 Video popup to fit the center of any screen?

Tags: css, html, video

I want to make an html5 video fit any size of the screen, if it's a iMac huge screen or if it's a phone, I want it to be responsive.

1) If it's a 4:3 monitor, it should show blank spaces (black bars) above and below video

2) If it's a super wide screen it should fit the height but show blank spaces left and right

3) Same with mobile, if it's portrait or landscape position

This is my HTML

```
<div class="video-container"> <!-- background darkener -->
      <video controls>
            <source src="img/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
   position: fixed; 
   top: 0; left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.video-container video {
  /* Here is what I want to know how to make it fit the way we want */
}
```

I don't mind using jQuery if more real time calculations are needed!
Thanks beforehand

Comment: Depending on what the purpose of this is, I would recommend not using the html video player, but instead embedding from elsewhere, such as youtube. Furthermore, I also wouldn't use a popup for the video, and it becomes difficult to use, diminishes the UX and may not be compatible with smaller screens or phones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me

```
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    background-image: url('your-video-poster.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 100;
}
```